# Create raw query with laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4

I've read something about raw query but not success till now. I needed to get the result from this SQL Server query by doing a raw query or another method can be possible to do this. This is the SQL Server query i need to get working with laravel 4

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),SYSDATETIME())
```

This is what i've tried:

```
DB::select( DB::raw('CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),SYSDATETIME())') );
```

I have this error message in my laravel log file: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.'`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It looks to me like you forgot to specify your table.

Comment: Is not a query from a table this query returns the current sql server datetime

Comment: You need to query a table if you want to SELECT a value, try to specify some system table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add SELECT for a raw query:

```
DB::select( DB::raw('SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),SYSDATETIME()) AS CurrentDateTime') );
```

DB::raw() is used to make arbitrary SQL commands which aren't parsed any further by the query builder so the passed query needs to be valid.

Comment: @lukasgeiter It is, unless you use [`DB::selectRaw`.](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_selectRaw). And no, you don't really need the `SELECT` clause because you're already using `DB::select`.

Comment: Im getting this error: `Cannot access empty property`

Comment: I have changed my query to include a column name for the returned time. It should now work.

Comment: Its been all night, looking for this LOL